# how to read/write "bits per sample "ifd tag in a tiff file (python)

Tags: python, image-processing, tiff

I'm struggling with IDF tag for "bits per sample". According to the documentation the type of this field is `short`

```
Code    258 (hex 0x0102)
Name    BitsPerSample 
Type    SHORT 
Count   N = SamplesPerPixel 
Default 1
```

a tag in a valid tiff file looks like this in hex:

`02 01 03 00 03 00 00 00 E2 01 00 00`

- `02 01` - the tag 258
- `03 00` - type short
- `03 00 00 00` - number of values 3
- `E2 01` - **this is what I have the problem with. how is this 3 shorts?**
- `00 00` - offset to the next ifd tag 0

how are the three shorts encoded to `E2 01` and how to read them? I expected 3 decimal values of 8,8,8 or 16,16,16. What am I missing? a short is an 8 bit value.

I'm using `struct` to read and write the tags and this one baffles me as this makes no sense with a single value of 482 as unsigned short (`H`):

`struct.pack('<HHIHH', 258, 3, 3, 482, 0)`

```
h short integer 2 (2)
H unsigned short integer 2 (2)
```

I bet I'm missing something obvious here. Any insights very welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the specification:

Bytes 0-1 The Tag that identifies the field.

Bytes 2-3 The field Type.

Bytes 4-7 The number of values, Count of the indicated Type.

Bytes 8-11 The Value Offset, the file offset (in bytes) of the Value for the field. The Value is expected to begin on a word boundary; the corresponding Value Offset will thus be an even number. This file offset may
point anywhere in the file, even after the image data.

So, the last 4 bytes are offsets.

Here's the TIFF standard document I found (page 14/15): https://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/doc/TIFF6.pdf

Comment: More information, including making your own bits: https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/faq.html#q3

Comment: I realised my mistake after posting the question. The part that I was missing was that it is the value only if you can fit it in 4 bytes. otherwise it is the offset to the actual data. I expected the data to be inline in the tag. my mistake.

Answer (score -1):

> For data with only one component (e.g. grayscale or black and white) you encode min, max, bits per sample directly in the tag, for RGB data the tag provides a pointer to the address for those values.

so in this case it is the offset to where the data is in the file. indeed in my test file it points to 3 short values of 8. I haven't seen this in the tiff documentation and only found this one reference online here:

https://paulbourke.net/dataformats/tiff/